# Vector Calculus Notation for "Cross" Quantities

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, vector-fields

This is just a notational question, to see if there is a better way to write the following quantities:

- $ v_1 = (f_{y} + f_{z}, f_{x}+f_{z}, f_{x} + f_{y} )$
- $ v_2 = (f_{yy} + f_{zz}, f_{xx}+f_{zz}, f_{xx} + f_{yy} )$
- $ t_1 = f_{xy}f_xf_y + f_{xz}f_xf_z + f_{yz}f_yf_z $

where $f_i$ is the partial derivative with respect to $i$, for $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. 
So, $v_1(x,y,z),v_2(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are vector fields, while $t_1(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}$ is a scalar field.

How can I write these with common operators on $f$  (e.g. $\nabla,\times,\cdot,\Delta,\nabla\cdot,\nabla\times,\otimes$ and so on) and/or are there some operators I am missing?

Comment: Question, What kinds of objects are these things?

Comment: @Triatticus They pop out as part of some larger expressions, from some differential geometry calculations

Comment: I was wondering if these were vectors, scalars, maybe higher order tensors

Comment: @Triatticus Oh, sorry. I have edited to clarify a bit. Is that alright?

Comment: Ah now its much more clear what we are dealing with

Comment: I believe that none of these are equivariant with respect to orthogonal change of coordinates, so you shouldn't expect to be able to write down anything in terms of operations which are.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hmm, thanks for that. That makes it a bit less satisfying I suppose. Any suggestion for other operators/notation/formulation without such invariance properties that might simplify it?